# jQueryMobile close dialog without page change

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

I'm developping a web app with jQM. It's a mono-page app with a lot of script-generated virtual pages. I use a lot of dialog, and occasionally, closing those dialog make my app go back to the start page (3 pages back in the history).

I can't make a test case, as it only occurs in complex cases, database based, and only on idevice, not on computer.

I found a lot of similar issues, but all for jQM 1.2 or older. I'm using jQM 1.5.3.

I added the `log-page-event.js` tool in my script, and it give me this :

First, the page is loaded "visite_client-86871"

```
[Log] pagebeforeshow (1422376478507) (log-page-events.js, line 44)
    page: div.visite_client.ui-page.ui-page-theme-a.ui-page-header-fixed.ui-page-footer-fixed#visite_client-86871
    data-url: visite_client-86871

[Log] hashchange (1422376481313) (log-page-events.js, line 44)
    location: http://m2.biocrm.fr/#visite_client-86871

[Log] pagehide (1422376482645) (log-page-events.js, line 44)
    page: div.ui-page.ui-page-theme-a#edit_visite
    data-url: edit_visite

[Log] pageshow (1422376483145) (log-page-events.js, line 44)
    page: div.visite_client.ui-page.ui-page-theme-a.ui-page-header-fixed.ui-page-footer-fixed.ui-page-active#visite_client-86871
    data-url: visite_client-86871

[Log] pagechange (1422376483171) (log-page-events.js, line 44)
    page: div.visite_client.ui-page.ui-page-theme-a.ui-page-header-fixed.ui-page-footer-fixed.ui-page-active#visite_client-86871
    data-url: visite_client-86871
```

Then, I click open the dialog :

```
[Log] popstate (1422376499968) (log-page-events.js, line 44)
    location: http://m2.biocrm.fr/#visite_client-86871&ui-state=dialog
    state.hash: 
[Log] hashchange (1422376501192) (log-page-events.js, line 44)
    location: http://m2.biocrm.fr/#visite_client-86871&ui-state=dialog
```

Then, I close the dialog :

```
[Log] popstate (1422376521377) (log-page-events.js, line 44)
    location: http://m2.biocrm.fr/#visite_client-86871
    state.hash: #visite_client-86871

[Log] hashchange (1422376521403) (log-page-events.js, line 44)
    location: http://m2.biocrm.fr/#visite_client-86871
```

And with no reason, it return to the home page "tournees"

```
[Log] pagebeforechange (1422376521407) (log-page-events.js, line 44)
    page: div.ui-page.ui-page-theme-a.ui-page-footer-fixed#tournees
    data-url: tournees

[Log] pagebeforechange (1422376521459) (log-page-events.js, line 44)
    page: div.ui-page.ui-page-theme-a.ui-page-footer-fixed#tournees
    data-url: tournees

[Log] pagebeforehide (1422376521501) (log-page-events.js, line 44)
    page: div.visite_client.ui-page.ui-page-theme-a.ui-page-header-fixed.ui-page-footer-fixed.ui-page-active#visite_client-86871
    data-url: visite_client-86871
```

What could I do to detect the reason of the error, or to prevent it ?
It looks like jQM is confused in his history. Is it possible to log it more precisely ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `data-history="false"` to the popup itself.

I'm not quite sure if there is a bug somewhere or not, but it work for me like this, so in case it helps someone...